# View no found, laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Buenas noches.

Amigos me aparece un error en Laravel, tengo controladores y rutas enlazadas correctamente, desde mi vista Index, en un etiqueta:

```
(<a href="/admin/agregar"</a>)
```

De esa forma estoy llamando la vista (agregar) que está dentro de la carpeta (admin).
Esta vista está generada en la función create del controlador, es decir que cuando yo llamé esta vista, está función create del controlador estará ejecutándose.
Pero no es así al ingresarla en el navegador.
Me aparece el error:
View(admin.ver) not found.

Nota: la vista "ver" se ejecuta dentro de la función show del controlador, la ruta es de tipo resource para abarcar todo el CRUD del controlador.

Intenté en el CMD con el comando:

- PHP Artisan caché:clear
- PHP Artisan config: cache.
- Y al refrescar la página sigue apareciendo el error.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Si hay un error que dice que la vista `admin.ver` no se encuentra eso quiere decir que en `resources/views/admin/` no hay ningún archivo que se llame `ver.blade.php`. Por lo tanto, deberías crearla o trasladarla.